# What is the scope of methods and properties of classes within App_Code in a web site project?

Tags: class

If I declare a for example property or enum in a class of App_Code, then what is the scope of that property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special about App_Code in terms of scope. The types declared in App_Code behave exactly as if they were declared in any other part of the web site.

Comment: @John: Do we have a constraint to declare all property and methods there as static ones?

Comment: It seems that I can't access to an enum declared in a class in App_Code section. but all other static members are accessable. How ever, I can't declare an enum as static member in the class.   What can I do?

Comment: @odiseh: there are no _special_ constraints, but there are normal ones. In particular, are you declaring your types within a namespace, but perhaps accessing them without one? Try creating a tiny enum or class, and then edit your question to include the source code.